# Adding another navigation for sub menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress site . And My site's header like this:

[image]

I want my submenu to open another section under header like header for example:

[image]

I tried a lot of things. I did a custom html/css header and try to add it to wordpress but my wordpres's theme doesn't let close it's header.
And actually it is hard to design another header.
I tried to customize my menu with custom csses but i couldn't . All i want to evolve my sub menu like second image.
English is not my main language , sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

try this and  add dropdown.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>CSS Template</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
li{float :left;
list-style-type:none;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li>opton ||
<li>opton ||
<li>opton ||
<li>opton ||
<li>opton ||
<li>opton ||
<li>opton ||
<li>opton ||
<li>opton ||
<li>opton ||

</ul>

</body>
</html>
```